# How to Login Dotnetnuke from another ASP.Net Application

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I have a dotnetnuke site. customers access this site with their username and password.
and, I am having another ASP.Net site. I want to let the customers enter the same dotnetnuke password & username to login here also. I searched everywhere in dotnetnuke table but could not find the password. How can I login to it? Is there any technique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetnuke uses ***AspNetSqlMembershipProvider*** by default, so the tables are the ones that 
have:  *aspnet_*

The password is encrypted (usually), but you 'may' be able to point another site to those same tables if you set it up to use AspNetSqlMembershipProvider.

Another option would be to write your own Authentication provider in DNN that checks the other website's username/password instead of using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider.

Google: DotNetNuke custom Authentication Provider.